# How to calculate the number of tests in a test set in QC?

Tags: quality-center

I have tests split to few test sets under the same folder. I can use the Live Analysis tab in order to see the number of tests in the folder. I wonder how can I see a number of tests per test set? Seems something very trivial but I can't figure out how this might be done.

**EDIT**: It seems that a similar question was answered [here](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Quality-Center-Support-and-News/hp-qc-test-lab-s-test-set-s-test-cases-count/td-p/4665309) but I don't know how to use these commands in QC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These steps assume you're using just the QC user interface. The answer you linked is better if you're looking for code.

**See the number of tests in a single test set:**

1. Navigate to the Test Lab module
2. Select a test set in the tree (not a folder).
3. In the right-hand pane, select the "Execution Grid" tab
4. Look at the bottom of the QC window, near the middle. The number of tests in the test set appears as "Test 1 of *xx*"

**Use Live Analysis to see the number of tests in each test set under the selected folder:**

1. From the Live Analysis tab, click Add Graph (you may have to remove one first)
2. Select Summary and click Next
3. Click the Group By drop-down list, and select "Status". Click Next.
4. Click the X-Axis drop-down list, and select "Test Set". Click Finish.

The graph should now show all the tests sets at any level under the selected folder. The number shown on the top of each bar is the total number of tests. Mouse over each color in the bar to see how many tests passed or failed in each test set.

You can also select different values in the "Group By" step above to see things like the planning status, priority, test author and so on.

Comment: Wow! How could I miss that? Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for! P.S. Just to make your answer maybe just a bit more precise, you should mention that once choosing the test set, "Execution Grid" tab must be chosen to see the number of tests. Thanks again!